# QT ODBC driver .mdb ms-access inserts not working above 1000 rows (windows)

Tags: qt, ms-access, odbc

I have tested many times my code on Windows.

(I need to use ms-access to upgrade an old app)

Trying to insert rows in a query using transaction or not, bindvalues or not, inserts doesn't go beyond 1061 rows.

I have tested with this code:

```
this->db_ = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");

QString archivo_elegido = QString(ruta_inicial_ + "cods.mdb");

cout << "archivo: " << archivo_elegido.toStdString() << endl;

this->db_.setDatabaseName(QString("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};FIL={MS Access};DBQ=%1;").arg(QDir::toNativeSeparators(archivo_elegido)));

if(!this->db_.open("",""))
{
cout << this->db_.lastError().text().toStdString() << endl;
}

int i = 0;
this->query = QSqlQuery(this->db_);

for(i=0; i< 20000;i++)
{
QString q;
q.append("INSERT INTO claves ");
q.append("(claveacceso) " );
q.append( "VALUES (:claveacceso) ");
this->query.prepare(q);
this->query.bindValue(":claveacceso", QString::number(i));
this->query.exec(); // No errors here.
cout << endl << " " << i;
}

this->db_.close();
```

Comment: You need to evaulate the error from query.exec().

Comment: query.exec(), doesn't return any error on "this->db_.lastError()".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an error.
I was testing, with GNOME MDB Viewer 0.7.1, based on http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net/.

The mdb viewer was **showing me only the fist 1000 rows**, even when I apply a query.

Answer (score 0):

```
QString q;
q.append("INSERT INTO claves ");
q.append("(claveacceso) " );
q.append( "VALUES (?) ");
this->query.prepare(q);
QVariantList varLst;
for(i=0; i< 20000;i++)
{
  varLst << QVariant::fromValue(i);
}
this->query.addBindValue(varLst);
this->query.execBatch();
```

Comment: Interesting.   But result is the same, only 1000 rows written to file.